# Plotting a heat map from three lists: X, Y, Intensity

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I don't get how to create a heatmap (or contour plot) when I have x, y, intensity. I have a file which looks like this:

```
0,1,6
0,2,10
....
```

So far:

```
with open('eye_.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
                for word in line.split():
                        l = word.strip().split(',')
                        x.append(l[0])
                        y.append(l[1])
                        z.append(l[2])
```

Tried using `pcolormesh` but it wants a shape object and I'm unsure how to convert these lists into a NumPy array.

I tried:

```
i,j = np.meshgrid(x,y)
arr = np.array(z)
plt.pcolormesh(i,j,arr)
plt.show()
```

It tells me that:

```
IndexError: too many indices
```

Can someone stop me from bashing my head against a keyboard, please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, there's a few steps to this.

First, a much simpler way to read your data file is with [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html). You can set the delimiter to be a comma with the `delimiter` argument.

Next, we want to make a 2D mesh of `x` and `y`, so we need to just store the unique values from those to arrays to feed to `numpy.meshgrid`.

Finally, we can use the length of those two arrays to reshape our `z` array.

(NOTE: This method assumes you have a regular grid, with an `x`, `y` and `z` for every point on the grid).

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('eye_.txt',delimiter=',')

x=data[:,0]
y=data[:,1]
z=data[:,2]

## Equivalently, we could do that all in one line with:
# x,y,z = np.genfromtxt('eye_.txt', delimiter=',', usecols=(0,1,2))

x=np.unique(x)
y=np.unique(y)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

Z=z.reshape(len(y),len(x))

plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Note: This depends on the order in which z-values are added, see test #1 and test #2 which give the same heatmap whereas it should not! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77820817/how-to-create-a-z-value-matrix-for-a-given-meshgrid-and-x-y-z-columns 
Do you see how to modify this?

Answer (score 7):

In case you don't have a regular grid (i.e. a value of z for each meshgrid value of x and y), you can use a more general method based on pandas data frames:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pypot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':x, 'y':y, 'z':z})
data = data.pivot(index='x', columns='y', values='z')
sns.heatmap(data)
plt.show()
```

The pivot method will use unique values from index and columns to construct a table with missing measurments set to NaN. The table can then be plotted as a heatmap.

Comment: I have the same problem which is mentioned above. I have 16,000 entries and 16 GB ram, because of the large data, table does not fit. I am not sure why this is happening, is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The index error arises from the fact that pcolormesh expects a 2D array while your `arr` is a 1D vector. Also if I understand correctly, your input file has the form

```
0,1,z
0,2,z
 ...
0,ymax,z
 ...
1,1,z
1,2,z
 ...
xmax,ymax,z
```

In that case `meshgrid(x,y)` will not work as it expects something like `meshgrid(range(xmax),range(ymax))` i.e. vectors without repeated values.

In your case you need to find out how many distinct x and y values there are and then simply reshape your vectors into 2D arrays.

```
shape = np.unique(x).shape[0],np.unique(y).shape[0]
x_arr = x.reshape(shape)
y_arr = y.reshape(shape)
z_arr = z.reshape(shape)
plt.pcolormesh(x_arr,y_arr,z_arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

To maximize generalization for input data, I would employ 2D interpolation to compute intensity (z-values) on a regular grid. This approach offers advantages over the accepted answer from [tmdavison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33943276/15330539), which necessitates sorted data on a regular grid, and [Vadim Smolyakov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44598662/15330539), known for being computationally inefficient, also for smaller datasets. This probably also answers the question of [basj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422096/basj).

## Lets generate the 3D data first

```py
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate the file
# generate datapoints placed unsorted and unevenly spaced 
n = int(3e2)
xyz_random = np.zeros((n,3))
xyz_random[:,0] = scipy.stats.uniform.rvs(loc=-1, scale=2, size=n)
xyz_random[:,1] = scipy.stats.uniform.rvs(loc=-1.5, scale=3, size=n)

# generate 2D intensities using a 2d gaussian
rv = scipy.stats.multivariate_normal([0.5, -0.2], [[2.0, 0.3], [0.3, 0.5]])
xyz_random[:,2] = rv.pdf(np.dstack((xyz_random[:,0], xyz_random[:,1])))

# optionaly: write the file
#np.savetxt('eye_.txt', xyz_random, delimiter=',')
```

## 2D interpolation to compute intensity (z-values) on a regular grid

```py
# optionaly: load the file
#xyz_random = np.genfromtxt('eye_.txt', delimiter=',')

# Create a 2D interpolator to calculate the intenisity at any position
z_interpolator = scipy.interpolate.CloughTocher2DInterpolator(xyz_random[:,:2], 
                                                              xyz_random[:,2])

# Define grid for the smoother contour plot
# The grid has equal spacing in both dimensions
# Calculate the spacing by sqrt(area/n_points)
d_xy = np.sqrt((xyz_random[:,0].max() - xyz_random[:,0].min()) * 
               (xyz_random[:,1].max() - xyz_random[:,1].min()) / n)
epsilon = 1. + 1e-9  # Add a little to include the endpoint in np.arange
x_uniform = np.arange(xyz_random[:,0].min(), xyz_random[:,0].max()*epsilon, d_xy)
y_uniform = np.arange(xyz_random[:,1].min(), xyz_random[:,1].max()*epsilon, d_xy)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_uniform, y_uniform)
Z = z_interpolator(np.dstack((X, Y)))
```

## Plotting

```py
# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=[8,4])

# Subplot 1: Scatter plot with tricontourf, which takes randomly positioned points
cb = ax[0].tricontourf(xyz_random[:,0], xyz_random[:,1], xyz_random[:,2])
plt.colorbar(cb, ax=ax[0], label='intensity')

# Subplot 2: Contour plot, which takes only points positioned on a grid
cb = ax[1].contourf(X, Y, Z)
plt.colorbar(cb, ax=ax[1], label='intensity')

# Scatter the original data points on both subplots
for ax_i in ax:
    ax_i.set_xlabel('x')
    ax_i.set_ylabel('y')
    ax_i.scatter(xyz_random[:,0], xyz_random[:,1], color='black', alpha=.5, s=3)
    
ax_i.scatter(X, Y, alpha=.5, s=3, marker='x')
    
ax[0].set_title('Positions randomly')
ax[1].set_title('Positions on regular grid')

plt.show()
```

[image]
The black points are the initial positions and the blue is the new equal spaced grid.

## The convex hull

To calculate and plot the convex hull, use the `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` function as shown below.

```py
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

hull = ConvexHull(xyz_random[:,:2])
convex_hull_path = xyz_random[hull.vertices,:2]

# close the hull by adding the first point also at the last
convex_hull_path = np.append(convex_hull_path, convex_hull_path[:1], axis=0)

plt.plot(*convex_hull_path.T, color='k')
```

Comment: Why isn't your regular grid `contourf` a rectangle? If you have the data on a rectangle then the contour plot should also be rectangular.

Comment: By definition, a 2D interpolator can't calculate points outside of the convex hull. Everything outside is extrapolating. To plot the input and grid positions, I reduced the number of points for both. Simply increase the grid's density by e.g. 1 magnitude (-> `d_xy = np.sqrt(...)/10`) and the grid recovers more areas close to the boundary of the convex hull.

Comment: Added code how the convex hull could be calculated and plotted to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a list into a numpy array you can use `np.asarray`.

Here's an easy way to get a heatmap, you should be able to adapt this example to your problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [5,6,7], [7, 8, 9]]
b = np.asarray(a)
plt.pcolor(b)
plt.show()
```

To read the data in like a list of lists you can do:

```
a = []
for line in file.readlines():
    a.append( map( int, line.split(',') ) )
```

in short. In a longer version it's the equivalent of:

```
a = []
for line in file.readlines():
    tmp = line.split(',')
    inttmp = [int(x) for x in a]
    a.append(inttmp)
```