# Plot intensity values to unsorted coordinates using mesh grid

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to plot a heatmap for `x, y, intensity` coordinates, similar to this question: [Plotting a Heat Map X,Y,Intensity From Three Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942700/plotting-a-heat-map-x-y-intensity-from-three-lists)

In my case, the data is not ordered and therefore the x and y coordinates cannot simply be reshaped into a mesh grid.

I would like to convert this:

```
x,y,intensity = [1,  1, 0.4
                 1,  0, 0.1
                 2,  2, 0.6
                 ...       ]
```

to this:

```
intensity     = [0.0, 0.1, 0.0
                 0.0, 0.4, 0.0
                 0.0, 0.0, 0.6
                 ...          ]
```

So my question is: how can I plot my intensity values for the x and y coordinates on a mesh grid? I also tried to use a for loop but could not find the right way to sort the data correctly.

The final result will be used to show x,y and color values in pcolormesh.

Comment: In your example `intensity`, shouldn't the value 0.1 be off the diagonal?  The point in `x, y, intensity` is `1, 0, 0.1`.

Comment: Thats correct, thank you

Comment: I also solved the problem now by manually sorting the values to the index in the mesh grid using a simple for loop