# Plot a heatmap from X, Y, Z coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, heatmap

I have 3 lists for X, Y, Z coordinates. How to plot a color heatmap from these 3 lists? Here it should be easily possible because `(x, y)` cover a rectangle [100, 120[ x [5, 15[.

First attempt : I can do a matrix `np.array(...)` from the `x, y, z` values but then, the x-axis, y-axis coordinates start from 0, which is not what I want (the x-axis should start at 100, the y-axis should start at 5 in the output plot).

```py
import numpy as np

X, Y, Z = [], [], []

for x in range(100, 120):
    for y in range(5, 15):
        X.append(x)
        Y.append(y)
        Z.append(np.random.random())

print(X)
print(Y)
print(Z)

plt.imshow(...)
```

How to make a heatmap from this data, specifically with x-axis / y-axis starting at a different value than 0?

Comment: Why aren't you using `np.meshgrid`? Have you looked into `plt.pcolormesh`?

Comment: @jared Yes, but this is the specific problem I'm encountering https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77820817/how-to-create-a-z-value-matrix-for-a-given-meshgrid-and-x-y-z-columns when using the answer from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942700/plotting-a-heat-map-from-three-lists-x-y-intensity