# How to create a Z-value matrix for a given meshgrid, and x, y, z columns?

Tags: python, numpy, heatmap, meshgrid

Let's say we would like to do a heatmap from three 1D arrays `x`, `y`, `z`. The answer from [Plotting a heat map from three lists: X, Y, Intensity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942700/plotting-a-heat-map-from-three-lists-x-y-intensity) works, but the `Z = np.array(z).reshape(len(y), len(x))` line highly depends from the order in which the z-values have been added to the list.

As an example, the 2 following tests give the exact same plot, whereas **it should not**. Indeed:

- in test1, `z=2` should be for `x=100, y=7`.
- in test2, `z=2` should be for `x=102, y=5`.

**How should we create the `Z` matrix in the function `heatmap`, so that it's not dependent on the
order in which z-values are added?**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def heatmap(x, y, z):
    z = np.array(z)
    x = np.unique(x)
    y = np.unique(y)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z = np.array(z).reshape(len(y), len(x))
    plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)
    plt.show()

### TEST 1
x, y, z = [], [], []
k = 0
for i in range(100, 120):
    for j in range(5, 15):
        x.append(i)
        y.append(j)
        z.append(k)
        k += 1

heatmap(x, y, z)


### TEST 2
x, y, z = [], [], []
k = 0
for j in range(5, 15):
    for i in range(100, 120):
        x.append(i)
        y.append(j)
        z.append(k)
        k += 1

heatmap(x, y, z)
```

**Edit**: Example 2: Let's say

```
x = [0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1]
y = [3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3]
z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

There should be a non-ambiguous way to go from the 3 arrays `x`, `y`, `z` to a heatmap-plottable meshgrid + a z-value matrix, even if `x` and `y` are in **random order**.

In this example `x` and `y` are in no particular order, quite random. How to do this?

Here a `reshape` like `Z = np.array(z).reshape(len(y), len(x))` would be in wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into `np.meshgrid`, you will see that there are two indexing schemes, `"xy"` (the default) and `"ij"`. When using `"xy"` indexing, `X` (the `np.meshgrid` result) increases along the columns and `Y` increases along the rows. This is the opposite of `"ij"` indexing where `X` increase along the rows and `Y` across the columns.

In your Test 1, if you were to reshape `x` using the typical c-style ordering (`np.reshape(x, (20, 10))`), you'd see that the resulting array increases along the rows, so it is using `"ij"` (and `y` increases along the columns). In your Test 2, the reshape (`np.reshape(x, (10, 20))`) would result in the reshaped `x` increasing along the columns, so it is using `"xy"` indexing.

That said, you can adjust your `heatmap` function call to take a parameter for which indexing to use when calling `np.meshgrid` and also reshape `Z` to be the same shape as `X`/`Y`.

```py
def heatmap(x, y, z, indexing="xy"):
    x = np.unique(x)
    y = np.unique(y)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing=indexing)
    Z = np.asarray(z).reshape(X.shape)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    p = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)
    fig.show()
    return p, fig, ax

# test 1 heatmap call
heatmap(x, y, z, "ij")

# test 2 heatmap call
heatmap(x, y, z, "xy")
```

Edit:

To handle the case with random-ordered data, you can deal with it by sorting along `x` and `y` in the proper order to achieve the desired indexing result.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def random_to_meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing="xy"):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    y = np.asarray(y)
    z = np.asarray(z)

    nx_unique = len(np.unique(x))
    ny_unique = len(np.unique(y))

    if indexing == "xy":
        shape = (ny_unique, nx_unique)

        x_sort = np.argsort(x)
        x = x[x_sort]
        y = y[x_sort]
        z = z[x_sort]

        y_sort = np.argsort(y)
        x = x[y_sort]
        y = y[y_sort]
        z = z[y_sort]

    elif indexing == "ij":
        shape = (nx_unique, ny_unique)

        y_sort = np.argsort(y)
        x = x[y_sort]
        y = y[y_sort]
        z = z[y_sort]

        x_sort = np.argsort(x)
        x = x[x_sort]
        y = y[x_sort]
        z = z[x_sort]
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Undefined indexing '{indexing}'.")

    X = x.reshape(shape)
    Y = y.reshape(shape)
    Z = z.reshape(shape)

    return X, Y, Z

def heatmap(x, y, z, indexing="xy"):
    X, Y, Z = random_to_meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing=indexing)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    p = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)
    fig.show()
    return p, fig, ax
```

You can test it on your sample input like so:

```py
x = [0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1]
y = [3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3]
z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

# xy
X, Y, Z = random_to_meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing="xy")

# ij
X, Y, Z = random_to_meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing="ij")
```

Comment: Thanks! It should be possible to assign the values automatically, even if `z` was in totally random order, right? Would you have an idea how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you clarify what that would look like?

Comment: Let's say `x = [0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1]`, `y = [3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3]`, `z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. Here there  should be a non-ambiguous way to go from the 3 arrays x, y, z to a heatmap.  x and y are in no particular order, quite random. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: In that case you'd have to decide whether you want `"xy"` or `"ij"` indexing and sort the arrays accordingly (and consistently).

Comment: It should be possible even with random order. If we loop on all (x, y, z) triplets, we could associate the right z-value to the right (x, y).

Comment: When using numpy you should avoid writing loops as much as possible. I think it's better to have two sorting calls.

Comment: @Basj See my updated answer regarding the randomized data.