# Interpolate points over a surface

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I have a function f(x,y) that I know for certain values of X and Y.
Then, I have a new function x,y= g(t) that produces a new series of points X and Y. for those  points, using the pre-calculated data I need interpolate.

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(X,Y):
    return np.sin(X)+np.cos(Y)

def g(t):
    return 3*np.cos(t)-0.5, np.sin(5*t)-1

x=      np.linspace(-4,4,100)
y=      np.linspace(-4,4,100)
X, Y=   np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z=      f(X,Y)
   
t=      np.linspace(0,1,50)
x_t, y_t=   g(t)
    
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(Z, extent=(-4, 4, -4, 4), origin='lower')
plt.scatter(x_t,y_t)
plt.show()
```

[image]
In other words, I need to obtain the shown curve with the previously calculated Z values, doing interpolation since in real life I dont have access to the actual function

Many thanks!

EDIT:

I found a function that does exactly what I want, but it produces the wrongs samples.

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interpn
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def f(X,Y):
    return np.sin(X)+np.cos(Y)

def g(t):
    return -np.cos(t), np.sin(2*t)

x=      np.linspace(-4,4,1001)
y=      np.linspace(-4,4,1001)
X, Y=   np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z=      f(X,Y)
grid= (x,y) 

t=      np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, 50)
x_t, y_t=   g(t)
xy_t=   np.stack([x_t, y_t], axis=-1)
Z_real= f(x_t, y_t)
Z_inter= interpn(grid, Z, xy_t)

fig= plt.figure()
gs=     fig.add_gridspec(1,2, hspace=0.1, wspace=0.1)
ax1=        fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0],projection="3d")
surf=   ax1.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, cmap=cm.jet, alpha=0.3)
ax1.scatter(x_t, y_t, Z_real)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5,  aspect=5)

ax2=    fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1])
ax2.plot(t, Z_real)
ax2.plot(t, Z_inter, '+')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What have you already tried, or do you have an explicit method in mind? There exist many interpolation methods with various advantages and disadvantages. Is your goal accuracy of the interpolation, speed, or other metrics? [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) is a good starting point:

Comment: look at kriging predictors.

Comment: Ive tried using griddata from scipy, but it interpolates over a grid instead of just over a line of points, so its too computationally heavy for what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently shared [a solution to a comparable question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77840480/15330539) that is applicable to your case as well. In brief, `scipy.interpolate` provides a range of 2D interpolation options. In this instance, I utilized `RegularGridInterpolator` or `CloughTocher2DInterpolator`, but you also have the option to employ another methods within `scipy.interpolate`.

`RegularGridInterpolator` outperforms `CloughTocher2DInterpolator` in terms of speed. However, the latter does not necessitate data to be arranged on a grid.

```py
import scipy.interpolate

# Option 1: RegularGridInterpolator
z_reg_interpolator = RegularGridInterpolator(
    (x, y), 
    f(*np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij', sparse=True))
)
Z_reg_inter= z_reg_interpolator(np.array(g(t)).T)

# Option 2: CloughTocher2DInterpolator with less datapoints to speed it up
n = 101
x_n= np.linspace(-4, 4, n)
y_n= np.linspace(-4, 4, n)
XY_n = np.meshgrid(x_n,y_n)

z_interpolator = scipy.interpolate.CloughTocher2DInterpolator(
    np.dstack(XY_n).reshape(-1,2),
    f(*XY_n).reshape(-1,1))
Z_clo_inter = z_interpolator(np.array(g(t)).T)
```

[image]